# Which is the equivalent of the StringToColor function for a TAlphaColor?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, firemonkey

I'm looking for the equivalent to the [`Graphics.StringToColor`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/Graphics.StringToColor) function to convert 
a string to an `TAlphaColor` (Color type used by Firemonkey). I searched in the [online Rad Studio help](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/) as well as in the related firemokey units without luck :(. I can write easily a function to convert these values but I prefear use a RTL function. Anybody knows if exist any function to convert a String to a TAlphaColor in delphi-xe2?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Yes exist such function and is called `StringToAlphaColor` and is declarated in the `System.UIConsts` unit.

```
function StringToAlphaColor(const Value: string): TAlphaColor;
```